# brew tap remote: Repository not found

Tags: git, macos, github, homebrew

I can't seem to tap into my own repository:

```
/Users/medialab
≈:≈ brew tap NMAAHC/NMAAHCmm
==> Tapping nmaahc/nmaahcmm
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/nmaahc/homebrew-nmaahcmm'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/NMAAHC/homebrew-NMAAHCmm/' not found
Error: Failure while executing: git clone    https://github.com/NMAAHC/homebrew-NMAAHCmm   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/nmaahc/homebrew-nmaahcmm --depth=1
```

But, I know for certain that `https://github.com/NMAAHC/homebrew-NMAAHCmm/` exists and I can't see why I would have any permission concerns since it is my repository.

I can easily tap into other repositories I don't own:

```
/Users/medialab
≈:≈ brew tap amiaopensource/amiaos
==> Tapping amiaopensource/amiaos
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/amiaopensource/homebrew-amiaos'...
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 0), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Tapped 10 formulae (46 files, 34.5K)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is [`hombrew-NMAAHCmm`](https://github.com/NMAAHC/hombrew-NMAAHCmm), not `homebrew-NMAAHCmm`.

```
                 ^^^^^^^
                    |- no e
```

Fix the typo (or [rename the GitHub repository](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-repository/)) and you will access your repo.

Comment: Oh damn. Thank you. @VonC